# How can I add my app in the list of Siri's bottom left question mark?

Tags: ios, iphone, siri

I have also added Siri uses description but my app is not listed on this list. Maybe I am missing something. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

[You can see the respected image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d8co.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ParameterVocabularies</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Parameter Names</key>
            <array>
                <string>INStartWorkoutIntent.workoutName</string>
            </array>
            <key>Parameter Vocabulary</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Vocabulary Item Identifire</key>
                    <string>step,wellness,sleep</string>
                    <key>Vocabulary Item Synonyms</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Vocabulary Item Phrase</key>
                            <string>Step Count</string>
                            <key>Vocabulary Item Examples</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>count my steps with Test</string>
                                <string>my wellness with Test</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>IntentPhrases</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Intent Name</key>
            <string>INStartWorkoutIntent</string>
            <key>Intent Examples</key>
            <array>
                <string>siri start my step count</string>
                <string>log my workout with Test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [AppIntentVocabulary.plist](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit) file to your project and include some Intent Examples. Siri will show these to the user as examples.

This AppIntentVocabulary is working for me perfectly (all sensitive data replaced with placeholders):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IntentPhrases</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>IntentName</key>
            <string>INRequestRideIntent</string>
            <key>IntentExamples</key>
            <array>
                <string>Book a ride with MyAppName.</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>ParameterVocabularies</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ParameterNames</key>
            <array>
                <string>INRequestRideIntent.rideOptionName</string>
            </array>
            <key>ParameterVocabulary</key>
            <array>
                <string>Word</string>
                <string>Word2</string>
                <dict>
                    <key>VocabularyItemIdentifier</key>
                    <string>Word2</string>
                    <key>VocabularyItemSynonyms</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPhrase</key>
                            <string>Word2</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemExamples</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>Get me a Word2 with MyAppName</string>
                                <string>Book a Word2 with MyAppName</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>VocabularyItemIdentifier</key>
                    <string>Word1</string>
                    <key>VocabularyItemSynonyms</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPhrase</key>
                            <string>Word1</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemExamples</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>Get me a Word1 with MyAppName</string>
                                <string>Book a Word1 with MyAppName</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPhrase</key>
                            <string>Word3</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemExamples</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>Get me a Word3 with MyAppName</string>
                                <string>Book a Word3 with MyAppName</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>VocabularyItemPhrase</key>
                            <string>Word2</string>
                            <key>VocabularyItemExamples</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>Book a Word2 with MyAppName.</string>
                                <string>Get me a Word2 with MyAppName</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks, @david Pasztor. But I already have AppIntentVocabulary.plist in my app with examples.

Comment: Are you sure it is set up correctly? Does your intents actually work?

Comment: Yes, It is working fine for Workout intents. Maybe I am missing something in AppIntentVocabulary.plist. Are you sure that Siri lists your app on the basis of  AppIntentVocabulary.plist?

Comment: Please include your AppIntentVocabulary.plist file in the question to see if it's correct or not. Yes, I am sure you need it, for my app it lists all the Intent Examples I defined in the vocabulary file.

Comment: Hey @ Dávid Pásztor you can find AppIntentVocabulary.plist file here. https://drive.google.com/a/threepillarglobal.com/file/d/0B-YCM5goXUEOYzUtRF9nZGhXUmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include the contents of the file formatted as code in the question, since I can't open the google drive link.

Comment: I have added the source code for AppIntentVocabulary.plist.

Comment: The Intent Phrases part looks mostly correct, except for one detail: your Intent Examples should include the name of your app and each intent domain has some specific keywords that need to be included in your Siri commands and hence in your Intent Examples in order for Siri to recognise them as Intents. You should test your commands in Siri and only use them as examples if Siri actually starts your workout for those commands. I have not worked with the `INStartWorkoutIntent` domain, but I am fairly sure, the keywords __start__ and __workout__ are necessary.

Comment: App name is already there in intent examples, I just removed them for some security reason before adding here. Could you please share me a demo AppintentVocabulary.plist file so that I can compare both.

Comment: Thanks, @Dávid Pásztor .